# Webview can't load images from local directory

Tags: android, webview

I can't load images in webview from my local path:

I have this string:

`Some content <img src='file:///storage/emulated/0/2.png?1533622895'> Ending content`

If I am loading this in a webiview as:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

It doesn't load my image. Just the text part only. I have this image locally saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image url contains arguments

```
?1533622895
```

Please remove it and try it. It should work

Comment: Thank you so much, man. But this is silly, why would this happen?